# Reload the tab using jquery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I'm using a jquery ajax to call a servlet. It gets called during the page load and populates the div using the ajax response(from the servlet).

I want to use this function again on a button click and reload the div. I'm having an issue here. Instead of reloading the div, all the values gets appended to the existing values in the table.

How can I reload this div by replacing the previous contents?

My code(HTML):

```
<div>
        <table id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Adds the rows dynamically from Jquery AJAX response -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function loadMyTable() {
    $.get('CallServlet', {}, function (responseText) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            var row = $("<tr/>")
            $('#table1').append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val1 + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val2 + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val3 + "</td>"));
        });
        $('#table1').dataTable();
    });
}
```

Comment: Simpler approach would be to wire the plugin up to your server side script and let it fetch the json. Plugin has reload functionality when pointed at server source also

Comment: Would you be able to point me at an example plugin?

Comment: same one you are currently using  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: And how can I reload the radio buttons too if I use this approach on tables?

Comment: <div id="radioset">
        <!-- Adds radio button dynamically from jquery-->
    </div>

Comment: do radios really need to be reloaded?

Comment: yes, cos I'm creating the radioset based on the table

Comment: ok, so you can use the ajax response probably to do what you need with radios. Numerous ways to do the ajax loading. Simplest is just point your url at plugin option. Can also integrate the ajax call yourself...or so the `empty()` that other answers suggest. More efficient not having to re-initialize the plugin to parse html when it could manage the data itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
$('#table1).datatable().fnDestroy();
```

This resolved the issue I had during reloading the table. Updated the code below

```
function loadMyTable() {
    $.get('CallServlet', {}, function (responseText) {
       $('#table1).datatable().fnDestroy();
        var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            var row = $("<tr/>")
            $('#table1').append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val1 + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val2 + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + value.val3 + "</td>"));
        });
        $('#table1').dataTable();
    });
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to empty your table before adding now rows. Use .empty(). Also append new rows to the tbody, not to the table.

```
function loadMyTable(){
         $.get('CallServlet', {
            }, function (responseText) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
                $('#table1 tbody').empty();
                $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                    var row = $("<tr/>")
                    $('#table1 tbody').append(row);
                    row.append($("<td>" + value.val1 + "</td>"));
                    row.append($("<td>" + value.val2 + "</td>"));
                    row.append($("<td>" + value.val3 + "</td>"));
            });
            $('#table1').dataTable();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the table1 content before adding new content to it.

```
$("#table1").epmty();
```

or

```
$("#table1 tr").remove();
```

or

```
$("#table1").html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Give Id to your Tbody

```
 <tbody id='table1tbody'>

 </tbody>
```

2) change append

```
function loadMyTable() {
    $.get('CallServlet', {}, function (responseText) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
        $("#table1tbody").html("");
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            var row="<tr>";
            row+="<td>" + value.val1 + "</td>";
            row+="<td>" + value.val2 + "</td>";
            row+="<td>" + value.val3 + "</td>";
            row+="</tr>";
            $("#table1tbody").append(row);
        });
        $('#table1').dataTable();
    });
}
```